# Sintaxis de loop cuando no tiene resultados

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un loop que recorre un array que viene de un select multiple y almacena en mysql los resultados.

El caso es que existe la opción que ese select no exista con lo que el loop no tiene sentido. He probado a meter una condición de si no existe el input que no ejecute ese loop pero me da error de sintaxis, así que había pensado que si no existe el select meter una variable que diga que el valor es 0 para que el loop solo se ejecute una vez.

Pero cuando hago desaparecer el select da error de sintaxis al guardar en mysql :(

este es el codigo que estoy usando:

```
if ($_SESSION['Empresa_Tallas'] == 1) { $TallaLin = $_POST["Cosa_MultiTallas"]; } else { $TallaLin = 0; }
```

Aquí defino si quiero usar tallas o no y si uso tallas leo el select "`Cosa_Multitallas`" y si no $TallaLin es 0.

Y luego tengo el for que hace el loop

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($TallaLin);$i++) { //hago un bucle que recorre todas las tallas
    //Guardado a mysql
}
```

y como variable para mysql de talla uso esta sintaxis dentro del for `$TallaLin[$i]`

el error que me da mysql es este:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0','','','','22','0','5','')' at line 1

lo que hay antes del error es justo la variable de $TallaLin[$i].

En cambio si $_SESSION['Empresa_Tallas'] es igual a 1 no da el error de sintaxis.

¿que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Podríamos ver la sintaxis de tu sentencia de MySQL?

Comment: Claro... no la he puesto porque es compleja y por no liaros... pero la pongo. @FranciscoRomero

Comment: Realmente creo que tu problema viene de que si no tienes `$_SESSION['Empresa_Tallas']` le metes un `0` a `$TallaLin`. Pienso que igual ese valor tiene que ser string y por eso te está dando fallo pero hasta que no veamos la consulta no podemos saberlo con certeza.

Comment: Pues ya me lo has resuelto XD en efecto TallaLin tenia que ser un string. @FranciscoRomero ¿Me lo pones como respuesta oficial que te de los punticos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema reside en que al asignarle el valor a `$TallaLin`, se lo estás asignando como un número entero, 0, cuando no tienes valor en `$_SESSION['Empresa_Tallas']`.

En realidad debería de ser un string, por lo que tu código debería ser así:

```
if ($_SESSION['Empresa_Tallas'] == 1) { 
    $TallaLin = $_POST["Cosa_MultiTallas"]; 
} else { 
    $TallaLin = "0"; //El 0 tiene que ir entre comillas para considerarlo como String
}
```